# HTTP Status errors: Only happen when running out of IDE

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have an AIR app and mostly I test it running out of the FlashBuilder IDE; sometimes I test it after I've installed it on my desktop.

Sometimes, but not always, when I upload files out of the IDE I get http status events with a code of 302; it's a redirect. Basically, the app doesn't think I'm logged in.

Whenever I test it as an installed AIR app I get no difficulties at all.

Have other people experienced difficulties like this when testing out of IDE vs. as an AIR app?

Thanks for any helpful tips!

Comment: I don't understand what " I upload files out of the IDE" means.  I have experienced no difficulties or differences running a debug session from  Flash Builder compared to running a production build.

Comment: It means I click "debug the app as....Desktop application" out of the FlashBuilder IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IDE will be running the app in ADL, not your installed AIR runtime.  I might be related to those to things being different versions?  I'm not completely up on how ADL differs from the runtime, but my guess is that's related to the issue you're seeing.

You can run adl yourself from the commandline.  The path is /PATH/TO/SDK/bin/adl, or adl.exe if you're on windows.  Running adl with no args will give you the adl version and help with running an app on the command line.

Wish I could be more helpful.

Comment: Thank you! It's definitely helpful to know that running the app from the IDE is in a different runtime than running it as an installed desktop app. I'll look further into it.